# logic does not work

Tags: python, recursion

I am having a little weird problem.

Ideally the program should terminate after the value of i reaches 10. But it keeps on executing till the below error is received.

ERROR:

```
  File "test.py", line 6, in recursive
    print "#%s - %s" % (string, num)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Program:

```
import os

def recursive(string, num):

    i=0
    while i<10:
        print "#%s - %s" % (string, num)
        recursive(string, num-1)
        i=i+1

recursive("Hello world", 9)
```

Comment: Go line by line with a debugger and see what happens. Also what is your question? Why is your logic wrong, or "fix my code, pls" ?

Comment: there's no stop condition in your "recursive" method

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: Here is a hint: Why do you have `i` if `num` is the counter?

Comment: Please recheck your learning material on recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You're decrementing `num` but never testing the value

You should have a terminal case which doesn't result in a recursive call

```
def recursive(string, num):

    if num == 0:
        return # terminal case

    i=0
    while i<10:
        print "#%s - %s" % (string, num)
        recursive(string, num-1)
        i=i+1
```

It's fair to say that this probably isn't the right fix for your program, but I'm not sure what it's *supposed to do*